# Group by - only fetch groups with X rows

Tags: mysql, laravel, group-by, eloquent, count

I want to fetch the `book_ids` for books which has `> X reviews` and `group` those to get the `average` rating for that book.

```
SELECT book_id, avg(rating) FROM `bookReviews` group by book_id` (where group count > 5)
```

Comment: are you asking for the query ?

Comment: If there is a way to achive it(?) yes I'd need some guidance - google didn't help much ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the query

```
SELECT book_id, AVG(rating) as average
FROM bookReviews
GROUP BY book_id
HAVING count(*) > 5;
```

This is the query builder;

```
return DB::table('bookReviews')
        ->select('book_id', DB::raw('AVG(rating) as average'))
        ->groupBy('book_id')
        ->having(DB::raw('count(*)'), '>', 5)
        ->get();
```